# Image manipulation in Python using MPI

Tags: python, parallel-processing, mpi, mpi4py

I'm trying to do some image manipulation using MPI (mpi4py) in Python. This is my code so far:

```
from mpi4py import MPI
from PIL import Image

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
size = comm.size #number of processors
rank = comm.rank #calling process rank
root = 0
if rank == 0:
    print "rank = 0 \n"
    img = Image.open('dog.jpg')
    width, height = img.size
    pix = list(img.getdata())
    for i in range(len(pix)):
        pix[i] = list(pix[i])
    chunks = [[] for _ in range(size)]
    for i, chunk in enumerate(pix):
        chunks[i % size].append(chunk)
else:
    print "rank != 0"

data = comm.scatter(chunks, root)
#do some pixel manipulations
data = comm.gather(data, root)
for i in range(len(pix)):
    pix[i] = tuple(data[0][i])
image = Image.new("RGB", (width, height))
image.putdata(pix)
image.save("test.jpg")
```

When I try to run it with

```
mpirun -np 1 python parallel.py
```

it works ok. But if i try to increase the number of processors, I get the following error

```
mpirun -np 3 python parallel.py
rank = 1
rank = 2
rank = 0 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parallel.py", line 21, in <module>
    data = comm.scatter(chunks, root)
NameError: name 'chunks' is not defined
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parallel.py", line 21, in <module>
    data = comm.scatter(chunks, root)
NameError: name 'chunks' is not defined
```

I'm running the code on a Ubuntu Virtual Machine using Virtual Box.
Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

This is not an MPI problem. `chunks` is undefined in the processes in which the `else:` branch of the conditional is taken, i.e. in all processes except rank 0. Simply add `chunks = None` there:

```python
...
if rank == 0:
    ...
else:
    print "rank != 0"
    chunks = None
...
```

It works with one process since in that case there is only one rank (0) and the else branch is never taken.